# use org.apache.http.entity.mime to upload a file to server but can't open it

Tags: java, web-services, file-upload, redmine

I use below code to upload a text file to server and it can work.

```
   `HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(uri+"/uploads.xml");
    MultipartEntity mpEntity = new MultipartEntity();
    FileBody cbFile = new FileBody(file);
    //insertValue
   httpclient.getParams().setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.PROTOCOL_VERSION,HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
    httpclient.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, defaultcreds);
    httppost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");
    mpEntity.addPart("userfile", cbFile);
    httppost.setEntity(mpEntity);
    //execute
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);`
```

But when I download the text file from server, I could not open it and find that other messages(the bold text ) be added in the text file.

**--RzBVXI2AHuDiIU5UHz-A1jZrpEg6a0JY
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="userfile"; filename="test.txt"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary**

CONTENT...

**--RzBVXI2AHuDiIU5UHz-A1jZrpEg6a0JY--**

THANKS!

Comment: That is the correct Mutlipart format. If you want help to read it, could you share the server side code. We have no idea what technology you are using.

Comment: I use this code to upload file to Redmine issue's attachment!

Comment: And if I upload a image. I still can't open it by double click.
Then I open this image use text edit , I found the Mutlipart format message is in that image file so that I can't open it.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I resolved it.
I use this code

`FileEntity entity = new FileEntity(file)`

to replace:

```
FileBody cbFile = new FileBody(file);mpEntity.addPart("userfile", cbFile);
```

and it works.

But I don't know why....